# Background location app not work in Samsung Android 8.0 devices

Tags: android, geolocation, location, alarmmanager, samsung-mobile

I have a location application that runs in background. To manage all this, I use periodic alarms to activate the localization process. The problem is that since the ***last update of SAMSUNG*** has stopped working on these devices. When the device is locked those alarms stop working. Just by activating the screen again, everything works correctly. I have tried several methods for managing alarms and the last tests have been done with the ***setExactAndAllowWhileIdle*** method

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

But the result has been the same. This behavior happens to me on ***Samsung devices with Android 8.0***.

Any help or suggestion will be welcome.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use Broadcast receiver to get location in version 8.0...i have test it was working for me

```
 private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
        // Note: for apps targeting API level 25 ("Nougat") or lower, either
        // PendingIntent.getService() or PendingIntent.getBroadcast() may be used when requesting
        // location updates. For apps targeting API level O, only
        // PendingIntent.getBroadcast() should be used. This is due to the limits placed on services
        // started in the background in "O".

        // TODO(developer): uncomment to use PendingIntent.getService().
//        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesIntentService.class);
//        intent.setAction(LocationUpdatesIntentService.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES);
//        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

> **Reference :** https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatespendingintent/MainActivity.java
>
> **Note:** Some of device is not working like OPPO,Vivo, due to security reason.. In this case you have to go to `Security permissions` ->
>   `autostart` -> then enable autostart from there.

Comment: Location will get  if  gps enabled...here is the my app you can check it https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kc.care.task

Comment: In Android 8 getService() will not work above code will work

Comment: @kubersingh yes you are correct..  `return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` it will not work for 8.0 so commented...for 8.0 you have to use broadcast recevier...